# Flash error (Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.)

Tags: flash, adobe

Trying to make a menu with navigation to different movies, but every time I click I get this error

> Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type.

after clicking it just proceeds to a blank screen.

```
mama_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, NavigateMama);

function NavigateMama(event:MouseEvent):void
{
//Optional but often needed. Stop the sounds for this page 
//before going to another page
SoundMixer.stopAll();

//To do navigation we need to call upon 2 Flash function libraries
var newdoc:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Mama.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
//This line loads the new page but it is invisible
loader.load(newdoc);
//We add the new page to the stage and now we have 
//both old and new pages mixed up on the stage - UGLY!
stage.addChild(loader);
//Clear out the old page to make way for the new.
stage.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

I am at my wits end, I pulled this from the adobe site. Anyone have an answer to make it work?

Comment: i have found the answer ..pretty much straight away.. any hints to kill this question?

Comment: for anyones interest what was happening was, the URLRequest was looking for Mama.swf file but Flash (even thou I saved the file as Mama.fla) was saving the .swf as Mama_Scene 1.swf .. which I just changed to the correct.